# Using HAProxy to Front Amazon S3

Tags: http, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have Direct Connect over a fast pipe to an AWS VPC and I'd like to use a cluster of HAProxy instances in my VPC to reverse-proxy one or more S3 buckets. This is so my users on premises can enjoy the increased bandwidth.

I guess the main question is whether this is doable, with the follow-on, "Is there a better solution for this than HAProxy?" I don't want to use an explicit proxy like squid because my only use-case for this is S3.

Assuming HAProxy is fine, I did a quick dummy setup for one bucket as a POC. When I connect directly to the bucket without credentials (simply to test connectivity), I see the "Access Denied" XML response I expect. But when I connect to the reverse-proxy, it seems to redirect me to https://aws.amazon.com/s3/. How am I screwing this up?

Here's my config (replace MY_BUCKET with any bucket name):

```
global
        daemon
        maxconn 256

defaults
        mode http
        timeout connect 5000ms
        timeout client 50000ms
        timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
        bind *:80
        default_backend servers

backend servers
        server server1 MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com:80 maxconn 100
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Per Pedro's request, here is the configuration I found that makes this work. As you can see, it's extremely bare bones. (I'm using an EC2 instance with two CPUs.)

```
global
        daemon
        nbproc 2
        nbthread 1

defaults
        mode tcp
        timeout connect 5000ms
        timeout client 50000ms
        timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
        bind *:80
        default_backend S3

backend S3
        server server1 s3.amazonaws.com:80
```

Answer (score 0):

Proxying from HAProxy to Amazon S3 is definitely possible! Below is a copy of our production config file. We are using HAProxy 2.2 but this should be backward compatible to older versions as well.

```
resolvers dns
    parse-resolv-conf
    hold valid 10s

frontend wwoof
    mode http
    bind *:80

    default_backend s3

backend s3
    mode http
    http-request set-header Host your-bucket.s3-website.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com
    http-request del-header Authorization
    http-response del-header x-amz-id-2
    http-response del-header x-amz-request-id
    server s3 your-bucket.s3-website.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:80 resolvers dns check inter 5000
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it to work in the meantime with a more minimal configuration--specifically, one that uses TCP mode and doesn't do anything with headers. How come you are deleting headers in your version? And was I wrong to think that TCP mode might perform a little better since this is just a passthrough?

Comment: I don't remember why we're deleting those headers (it's been quite a while). At this point I'm just leaving it alone :) Would you mind sharing your solution using TCP? I am actually quite interested, and there are few examples using HAProxy + S3 out there. You could just add it as an answer below.

Comment: Done, Pedro. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I think that looks great! Neat and simple. I will give it a shot in our staging environment and see if I notice any issue. You're probably right that TCP would deliver better performance than HTTP. Thanks for sharing your solution John-Paul.